# Socket.io button listeners not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, mobile-browser

I'm writing a web app in Node.js and socket.io. I have a couple of button listeners that pick up when a user has clicked a button and then performs a specific action (in this case, playing a small tone). For some reason, these buttons work perfectly in Chrome/Chromium, but don't work in Firefox or on mobile browsers (I've tested it with Safari on iOS and Chrome on Android).

Here's my code:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');

var long = document.getElementById('long');
short = document.getElementById('short');

long.addEventListener('click', function() {
socket.emit('long', socket.id);
socket.broadcast.emit('audio file', {
    audio: true,
    audioBuffer: buf
});
});

short.addEventListener('click', function() {
socket.emit('short', socket.id);
socket.broadcast.emit('audio file', {
    audio: true,
    audioBuffer: buf2
});
});

socket.on('long', function(data) {
socket.broadcast.emit('audio file', {
    audio: true,
    audioBuffer: longbuf
});
console.log("Transmitting", socket.id);
});
socket.on('short', function(data) {
socket.broadcast.emit('audio file', {
    audio: true,
    audioBuffer: shortbuf
});
console.log("Transmitting", socket.id);
});
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(5000, function() {
console.log("Listening to requests on port 5000")
});

app.use(express.static('public'));

var io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
console.log('New transmitter', socket.id);
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/sounds/trollism.wav', function(err, 
longbuf) {

    socket.on('long', function(data) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('long', data);
        console.log("Long press from " + socket.id);
        socket.broadcast.emit('audio file', {
            audio: true,
            audioBuffer: longbuf
        });

    });
});
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/sounds/trollism2.wav', 
function(err, shortbuf) {

    socket.on('short', function(data) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('long', data);
        console.log("Short press from " + socket.id);
        socket.broadcast.emit('audio file', {
            audio: true,
            audioBuffer: shortbuf
        });

    });
});
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Edit: Decided to go jfriend00's route and make the client call the server via socket.emit(). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure this all works on dektop browsers?

Comment: @wrangler it fully works on Chrome (Ubuntu desktop). I'm able to get the audio output in Firefox (also Ubuntu desktop) and Chrome mobile, but pressing the buttons don't trigger the listener functions. Safari on iOS doesn't work at all.

Comment: Try `console.log` inside Event listeners and see whether the listeners are being called, if not called then may be the problem arises from buttons Dom in html if called then i think message is not emitted after event is listened.

Comment: YOu need to diagnose whether your client code is getting the right events and executing the code you expect or whether this is a pure client-side event issue and you aren't getting the client event handlers you want.  Then, you need to put a bunch of logging in the server to see exactly what it is receiving to track down where you aren't getting what you expect.  This is how you debug problems like this.  We can't do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, `socket.broadcast.emit()` is not a client-side method.  That's something that is available on the server.  A client sends ONLY to the server with `socket.emit()`.

A client doesn't send messages directly to other clients - that's not how socket.io works.  socket.io is a connection from your client to your server.  While the method may work on some platforms and send a message to your server, it is not documented and should not be used on any client platform.

Perhaps the iOS implementation either does nothing or has some sort of internal error when you attempt to use the undocumented `socket.broadcast.emit()`.  You should be using `socket.emit()` instead.

If you want to relay messages to other clients from a client, you create your own message that you send to the server for that activity and then when the server receives that message, the server can then broadcast to other clients.